# Find Number of Occurences for Maximum Value for each unique item in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get this working by some simple method.

Say, there is a table for Cars Sold and with the name of the Car Model and the Price the Car was sold for

Eg.,

```
    CarName     Price
    AcuraLegend 30000 
    AcuraTSX    40000 
    HondaCivic  20000 
    HondaCivic  22000 
    HondaCivic  22000 
    ToyotaCamry 18000
```

and then 2900 more entries

What I need is to find the maximum price each car was sold for and the number of that type of car sold for the maximum amount. So, if we were to use the above dataframe, assuming that the max price paid for HondaCivic in the entire dataframe was 22000, and only 2 cars were sold for this price, for HondaCivic I would have,

```
CarName     MaxPricePaidForCar         NumberofCarsSoldforMaxPrice
HondaCivic      22000                  2
```

Now, I have managed to put this together with a rather tedious way of using tapply and merge, etc etc.

Any suggestions on a simpler method would be very helpful,

Comment: Based on your comments I edited the question to better reflect what you meant. If I got something wrong, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 6):

To do this for each unique type of car, you can use `ddply` in the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(carList,.(carName), .fun = summarise, maxPrice = max(Price), 
                                            numCars = sum(Price == max(Price)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach using `data.table`. If your data frame is large and speed is of concern, this should give you approximately a 4x speedup.

```
library(data.table)
carT = data.table(carList)
carT[,list(maxPrice = max(Price), numCars = sum(Price == max(Price))),'carName']
```

Comment: I recently found you've been promoting `data.table` here on Stack Overflow for quite some months. Thank you!

Comment: thank you for writing the package. i frequently deal with large amounts of data and was thinking of moving out of R, till I found `data.table` :)

Answer (score 1):

I quite like `cast` from the `reshape` package for these little tasks:

```
cast(df, CarName ~., c(function(x) sum(x == max(x)),max))
```